# Is there a rule of thumb in Instantiating in Android?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android programming and I came across with this code below.

```
public void email(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
                                  0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .setTicker("NEW EMAIL!!!")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText("This is a new E-mail!!!")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(
            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

It made me angry to see that creating an instance of `PendingIntent` is:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(etc.)
```

and creating an instance of `NotificationManager` is:

```
 (NotificationManager)getSystemService(etc.)
```

While creating an instance of  `NotificationCompat.Builder` is:

```
new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
```

How can you know when to use the word "new" or the method `getSystemService()` and so on. Is there a universal rule of instantiating or should I learn it one by one, for every class?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: Did i do this marking correctly with that green checking sign? Or is there another process? I'm new to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the classes in the Android framework can be instantiated using `new`:

```
Fragment f = new Fragment();
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout();
Intent i = new Intent();
```

Then there are other classes that should never be instantiated by the programmer using `new`. `Activity` is an Example. `Application` is another.

In the examples that you have cited, the term *Builder* is a reference to the [**Builder Pattern**](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html). The `PendingIntent` class has methods like `getActivity()` and `getService()` because it fetches a new `PendingIntent` of the type specified by the programmer, i.e. an `Intent` for an `Activity` or `Service`.

With experience, you will learn more about when to use `new` directly, when to use a *Singleton*, and so on. These are Java conventions whose purpose is to increase efficiency and code reuse.

Answer (score 1):

> creating an instance of PendingIntent is: PendingIntent.getActivity(etc.)

That is "obtaining an instance". Whether `getActivity()` creates a new instance, retrieves one from a cache, etc. is up to the implementation of `PendingIntent`.

> creating an instance of NotificationManager is: (NotificationManager)getSystemService(etc.)

That is "obtaining an instance". Whether `getSystemService()` creates a new instance, retrieves one from a cache, etc. is up to the actual implementation of `Context` (not a public part of the Android SDK).

> Is there a universal rule of instansiating

No. I am not aware that there is such a rule in any programming language.

That being said, usually if you are not supposed to use a constructor, there is no public constructor. For example, you will notice that [there is no public constructor on `PendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), and [there is no public constructor on `NotificationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html).